# Notation in expectation

Tags: probability, notation, markov-process

I know this question has been asked several times before, anyway I don't find the answer to my problem - on some lecture notes I read the following statement:

Let$ P_t $ be a Markov semigroup acting on the space of bounded measurable functions. Then
$$
(P_t f)(x) = \mathbb{E}_x[f(X_t)]
$$
For each bounded measurable function $f$. I don't understand how to interpret the right and side. Any guess?

Comment: Your edit is an entirely different question from your original. In case you don't know, it's considered poor form on SE to change your question after the original one has been answered. Please avoid doing this in the future. I'll try to have a think about your new question and get back to you if I have an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Average over $x$. In other words, if $x$ has marginal CDF $P$, the right-hand side is $\int f(X_t) dP(x)$.

Comment: I don't understand. Reading further I found the following: $$ (P_tf)(x) = E[f(X_t)|F_0](x) = E_x[f(X_t)]$$ And this seems not even make sense as x is a point in the state space, and $E[f(X_t)|F_0]$ is defined on some probability space $\Omega$...

Comment: So you have any idea @J.G. ?

Comment: @jJjjJ Ah; well in that case, the subscript $_x$ didn't mean what I thought it did. The intended meaning is probably $\int f(X_t) p(X_t|F_0) dX_t$, where $X_t$ has conditional pdf $p$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Computation.

Answer (score 2):

This should really have been defined in your lecture notes (if you can't find it, try harder), but when I took Markov processes, our notational convention was that

$$ \mathbb E_x[f(X_t)] = \mathbb E[f(X_t) \vert X_0 = x]. $$

The comment you left on [J.G.'s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2880538/388944) seems consistent with this interpretation.

Comment: It seems that your guess is correct, but I have still some doubts, please read my EDIT @Theoretical Economist

Answer (score 0):

The $t$ index just means that the stochastic process is dependent on time; so think of the process at a fixed time.

Then

$$\mathbb{E}_x[f(X)] = \int f(x)p(x)dx  \approx  \frac{1}{n}  \sum_{i}^{n} f(x_i) $$

where $x_i$ is sampled from $p(x)$ which is the distribution of the random variable $X$.

Also, the initial condition of the process $X$ can be a fixed state $X(0)=x$ or a distribution i.e.: $X(0)=N(\mu, \sigma)$; hence, the $F_0$ notation.